# Is this really a good answer?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, up-votes

This [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/160091/75000) to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/160089/75000) doesn't seem to seriously address what's being asked, and looks to me like the responder is making a joke (aka a glorified comment). While I don't know much about the finer details of the LOTR series, I can't find myself believing most of what they said, and the comments seem to agree. As of this writing, it has four upvotes, so I was wondering if there was something I'm missing as far as the content or quality of this answer. If not for the positive votes, I'd probably flag it.

Comment: Now that I've looked at it, I am also baffled. While it probably doesn't qualify for any form of flagging, it definitely should be downvoted rather than upvoted.

Comment: @Ixrec That was my second option

Comment: And the answer's score has nosedived since you asked this question. I am now pleasantly un-baffled.

Comment: I think the essential point is that it is not *wholly* a joke. Answers that are nothing but jokes (even if they could be interpreting as addressing a question) tend to be considered non-answers and deleted (like when someone says that the Flash helped Tyrion get somewhere fast on GoT or something). Answers that are humorous but still seriously address the question (accurately or not) stay up.

Comment: In other words, it looks like a genuine (if humorous and somewhat incorrect) answer, not a mere joke. For example, the bit about the tower collapsing because Sauron built it with the Ring looks like a definite attempt at an answer (and is actually correct).

Comment: @Ixrec The score is back in the positives

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - And back into the negative again, where it belongs

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance

Comment: When I see these sorts of things, I am reminded of the Wizard's First Rule.

Comment: @can-ned_food Which is?

Comment: It appears that this answer was removed. I wish I made a screen grab. Is there any way to get a copy? I can't find it in the wayback machine.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: 10k'ers can still see it.  The rest of us will just have to use our imaginations.

Answer (score 13):

**Q. Is it *an* answer?**
Yes.

**Is it a *good* answer?**
No.

---

### Why is it a bad answer?

**Because it's a bunch of unsourced assumptions, that's why;**

> which is no longer able to maintain the cohesion necessary to project
>   his 'Eye-Form' into our dimension

**Says who?**

> it is assumed he fell the remaining 1.5k (5,000ft) to his death.

**"Assumed" by who?**

> This was caused from the rapid release and detonation of the volatile
>   and flammable chemicals being used to maintain the eye-flame,

**Huh?**

> stemming from failure of an O-ring on the anti-backflash device on one
>   or both of the nozzles in the 'horns' of the tower used to create the
>   effect.

**Wut?**

Comment: That last one gets me every time!

Comment: the O-ring / nozzle comment must be a reference to the Space Shuttle Challenger accident - which is.....dark, to say the least.

Comment: To offer potential context, this looks like it's from someone who migrated from /r/AskScienceFiction, which has a similar Q&A format, but demands that answers be as in-universe as much as possible.  In the absence of sources, rampant speculation/fan-theories are permitted, so long as it's plausible.  Were this posted on that subreddit, this answer would probably have been well-received.

Comment: Being old enough to remember seeing the only real-world example live, I'm never going to find any passage containing the phrase "o-ring failure" funny. "In bad taste" seems like a gross understatement to me. Anyone at least 20 years old and familiarity with the works for Richard Bachman would probably be equally (well maybe a bit more) disgusted by a supposedly humorous reference to the end of *The Running Man* (the novella).